# Redirect user using rules after competing registration in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-rules

A little bit of background of what I've been doing before I go straight to my question.

***I used Toboggan Drupal Module and let the user automatically log in after complete registration***

At the registration page, there's a Price Plan that the user has to chose from.

- $4.95
- $14.95
- $29.95

**$4.95:**

**ID:** p_1

**Redirects to page(page name):** 001

**$14.95:**

**ID:** p_2

**Redirects to page(page name):** 002

**$29.95:**

**ID:** p_3

**Redirects to page(page name):** 003

After completing all the registration fields including the price plan. It will be redirected to a corresponding page listed above instead of being redirected to mysite.com/user

[image]

Now here's the problem goes,

I've created a rule which is after the user successfully registered.

[image]

**The action is execute custom php code**

```
<?php
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;

$result = db_query("SELECT field_price_plan_value FROM field_data_field_price_plan WHERE entity_id = :uid",
    array(
        ':uid' => $uid
    ))->fetchField();

if ($result == "p_1") {
    header("Location: 001");
} else if ($result == "p_2") {
    header("Location: 002");
} else if ($result == "p_3") {
    header("Location: 003");
}
```

After the user registered, the user didn't redirect to a certain page. For example, **I've picked $14.95** after my successful register, I should be redirected to **mysite.com/002** but instead I just redirected to default mysite.com/user.

Any possible solution for this? A help would be nice.

I even used drupal_goto() instead of header(), still didn't worked though.

***Edit***

Here's some kind of duplicate questions, but yet, I still didn't manage to apply well on my problem.

[How to redirect user to a specific page after they login if they belong to a certain role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429767/how-to-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-after-they-login-if-they-belong-to-a-cer)

[Drupal 7 system redirect through rules module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312672/drupal-7-system-redirect-through-rules-module)

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50300/how-to-redirect-anonymous-users-to-login-page-using-rules-module